# Is it possible to use the existing fastest TSP route on a graph when calculating it with a new node?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

If I have the fastest route to visit all the nodes on a graph and return to the original node (the travelling salesman problem), can I use this route to calculate the new fastest route when another node is added to the graph?

Essentially, is there a link between the fastest route around $n$ nodes and the fastest route around $n + 1$ nodes. If so what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, you can "use" the route. If you take the fastest route through the original $n$ nodes, then add a short detour through the additional node, you now have a *pretty good* route through the new graph of $n+1$ nodes. It's probably not optimal, but it's not worthless either, because it gives you an upper bound on the optimal solution. And that upper bound is a useful input for a branch-and-bound algorithm. Using it will enable you to discard bad branches sooner. So, finding the new fastest route will take less time than it would if you had no information to start with.

On the other hand, **no**: don't expect the new route to look like the old one. It's not *that* easy to solve TSP.